# LEFT JOIN with a condition

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I need to join two tables. I only want to show matches where `users.private` = 0

```
feeds
id     user_id
100    1
101    NULL
102    2

users
id   private
1    1
2    0
```

I have seen many related questions, and the answer is always to move the WHERE condition into ON instead. But if i do this:

```
SELECT `feeds`.`id`, `feeds`.`user_id` AS `feed_user_id`, `users`.`id` AS `user_id`,  `users`.`private` 
FROM  `feeds` 
    LEFT JOIN `users` ON `feeds`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
        AND `users`.`private` = 0
```

This returns

```
id     feed_user_id  user_id  private
100    1             NULL     NULL
101    NULL          NULL     NULL
102    2             2        0
```

What I WANT it to do is exclude the first row id 100. (So I guess that is not really a LEFT JOIN -> I want it to LEFT JOIN if the condition is met, otherwise exclude) How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to show those `feeds.id` where `feeds.user_id` is `null` also? (I.e., do you want to show id 101, or just 102?)

Comment: @iamnotmaynard yes, I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two separate condition clauses, one on the JOIN and one on the SELECT, like so:

```
SELECT `feeds`.`id`, `feeds`.`user_id` AS `feed_user_id`, `users`.`id` AS `user_id`,  `users`.`private` 
FROM  `feeds` 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `feeds`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
WHERE `users`.`private` = 0 OR `feeds`.`user_id' IS NULL
```

The problem with your current approach is that the join is treating private users as if they don't exist, rather than saying "this person exists and I should exclude this row from the results".

Comment: Thanks for the query and explanation. Earlier I was trying `users.private = 0 OR users.private IS NULL` but something felt wrong. I like this much better